# how to insert a variable with data in jquery?

Tags: jquery

If I have a variable defined in jquery as follows:

```
var insertString = "<div id='divid'>";
    insertString += "<input type='text' name='textbox' value=''>";
    insertString += "</div>";
```

Now, if I want to insert the above variable 'insertString' before some DOM element, how can I do it? I tried Something like below with no success

```
  insertString.insertBefore("body");
```

Comment: A string does not have an `insertBefore` method, only jQuery objects do. You might want to try: `$('body').prepend(insertString)`.

Comment: @pimvdb, that'll insert the string right *after* `<body>` which isn't what is asked for (although is quite possibly what is wanted).

Comment: @tjm: I don't really know - why would you insert a `div` before the `body` element anyway?

Comment: @tjm: After? Look up what "prepend" means.

Comment: use $('body').appendTo(insertString);  //jQuery will convert your string into DOM nodes.  Cha ching!

Comment: @Tomalak I'm quite aware what prepend means, but what I said is true. Note I said it will insert after `<body>`, *not* after the `body` element.

Comment: @John: You mean `append`, not `appendTo`. And you probably mean "prepend".

Comment: @tjm: Aha, ok. How confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to wrap your html in a `$()` function thus passing it to jQuery and creating a jquery object. Then you can operate on that object by chaining jQuery functions like this:

```
$(insertString).insertBefore("body");
```

But it would be pretty weird to put a div BEFORE the body... maybe it is better to prepend it to the body like this...

```
$(insertString).prependTo("body");
```

Comment: You mean `prependTo`, or reverse the target and source.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend inserting that before the body tag as that content belongs inside of it, but here's how you would insert it before an element with id='foo'.

```
$(insertString).insertBefore('#foo');
```

**Update:**
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/tZDAr/)'s a fiddle to test the functionality

Answer (score 3):

Don't insert *before* the body. Contents goes *in* the body.

Why not [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) instead?

Also, you attempt to run a jQuery member function on a string, not on a jQuery object. You need to form the jQuery object from the string.

Finally, you forgot to close your `input` tag.

[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9PSuK/):

```
$(function() {
    var insertString = "<div id='divid'>";
    insertString += "<input type='text' name='textbox' value='' />";
    insertString += "</div>";

    $(insertString).prependTo("body");
});
```